# Google App Engine update or rollback not working

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-eclipse-plugin

I am having trouble deploying my Google app engine project. It tells me to do a rollback, so I do that and it says it succeeded... but when I redeploy it fails again!

I try changing the version of my app and update but it STILL fails with the same error message.

I tried deploying the same project to on of my other app engine applications and it works fine.

It's like I have been permanently locked out of doing updates to my app!!
Has anyone experienced this before?

Here is the output from deployment.

```
Preparing to deploy:
    Created staging directory at: 'C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg6042733420741259764.tmp'
    Scanning for jsp files.
    Compiling jsp files.
    Scanning files on local disk.
    Scanned 250 files.
    Scanned 500 files.
    Scanned 750 files.
    Scanned 1000 files.
    Scanned 1250 files.
    Scanned 1500 files.
    Scanned 1750 files.
    Scanned 2000 files.
    Scanned 2250 files.
    Scanned 2500 files.
    Scanned 2750 files.
    Scanned 3000 files.
    Scanned 3250 files.
    Scanned 3500 files.
    Scanned 3750 files.
    Scanned 4000 files.
    Scanned 4250 files.
    Scanned 4500 files.
    Initiating update.
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=codeavengers&version=alpha&
409 Conflict
Another transaction by user mrwwalmsley is already in progress for app: s~codeavengers, version: alpha. That user can undo the transaction with "appcfg rollback".
```

Comment: After the rollback, try updating to a different version (say, 'alpha1').

Comment: Dave is correct. Try to upload the app on a newer version. Also delete the previous one which was stuck in the update phase.

Comment: As my question states... I have tried that. It does not matter what I change the version to I still get the same error message. Also, I did delete alpha version. The only way I have been able to upload is to upload to a completely new APP which is not ideal! I have had failed updates many times before, and had no problems after rollback.

Comment: This app has been running on app engine for almost 2 years now, and I have never had a problem like this. There are 2 accounts that have access to the app. Perhaps this has something to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, I needed to migrate my application-level settings to the module/version level.

> Go to the Performance section of the Application Settings page in the Admin Console, and you should see a section explaining the migration process.

I found the solution here: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10021#c10

Comment: Awesome! Just added the info from Google... as your answer was a bit vague for me. I didn't know what "module/version level" meant. I guess I had the problem a day to early to find that post!!

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps given below and run command in cmd prompt:

1) Go to bin directory of SDK: `F:\RD\Google App Engine\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.12\bin`

2) Execute command: `appcfg.cmd rollback "E:Workspace\Ankit\war"`

It will ask for username and password of your gmail account and rollback the partial changes done.

And then you can again upload the project using eclipse.