# Why would I be unable to rollback a GAE update transaction?

Tags: google-app-engine

When trying to update my application on GAE I get a message stating another transaction is in progress and it suggests undoing the the transaction by running `appcfg rollback`.  I have encountered this many times before and running the `appcfg rollback` has always resolved the issue.  This time it is not working.

I ran the `appcfg rollback` and it appears to have worked successfully but I am still unable to update my app (I continue to get the 409 Conflict error).  I have tried changing versions of the app I am updating and I still get the same error.  I was able to deploy my code to a different app, so the issue is specific to this one GAE instance.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what might be causing this problem?

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061582/google-app-engine-update-or-rollback-not-working

That question doesn't have an answer, so this might be an App Engine bug.  You'd want to file a production request on App Engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to migrate my application-level settings to the module/version level.

I found the solution here:
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10021#c10